Why do some US states prioritize voter lists to select federal jurors?
I read on  wkyc.com (mirror 1, mirror 2):

Some states, like Pennsylvania and Florida, prioritize voter lists for federal jurors, though local and state juries can be drawn from DMV and state ID records. Colorado’s federal courts use voter and driver databases for selection.

Why do some US states prioritize voter lists to select federal jurors?

Are you sure it's a state question when the relevant court districts are federal?

I am not seeing in the Pennsylvania or Florida link anything about people not being registered voters.

Frame challenge: Why not? A single list is less likely to have problems. Merging multiple sources of personal identifying information can be, and often is, problematic. What other single list other than voting information is more likely to show those eligible to serve on a federal jury than is voting registration (or actual voting)?

@DavidHammen  "Why not?" discourages voting.

@jeffronicus idk

@FranckDernoncourt By "why not" I meant why not use a single list, of which voter registration is almost certainly the most comprehensive. As I noted, merging brings complications that reliance on a single list does not. And how does reliance on voting registration for federal jury duty discourage voting? There might be a small number of people who don't register to vote just because courts (not just federal) use those lists for jury selection. Those are the very people most judges and most lawyers don't want to be on a jury.

@DavidHammen "Those are the very people most judges and most lawyers don't want to be on a jury." this is one more reason not to prioritize voter lists to select federal jurors.

To be a federal juror, you need to be a citizen and 18 years old. It is easier to verify that from the voter rolls then the drivers license list.
Juror Qualifications, Exemptions and Excuses

be a United States citizen;
be at least 18 years of age;


From USCourts.gov:

All [federal] courts use the respective state voter lists as a source of prospective jurors. If voter lists alone fail to provide the court and litigants with a representative cross section of the relevant community, courts use other sources in addition to voter lists, such as lists of licensed drivers in the district, in an attempt to comply with the section 28 U.S.C. §1861 of The Jury Selection and Service Act.

The referenced section reads, in entirety as (emphasis mine)

It is the policy of the United States that all litigants in Federal courts entitled to trial by jury shall have the right to grand and petit juries selected at random from a fair cross section of the community in the district or division wherein the court convenes. It is further the policy of the United States that all citizens shall have the opportunity to be considered for service on grand and petit juries in the district courts of the United States, and shall have an obligation to serve as jurors when summoned for that purpose.

8 U.S.C. §1862 also applies:

No citizen shall be excluded from service as a grand or petit juror in the district courts of the United States or in the Court of International Trade on account of race, color, religion, sex, national origin, or economic status.

8 U.S.C. §1863 states that every district court shall develop a plan for random jury selection. Among other things this plan must specify are

[W]hether the names of prospective jurors shall be selected from the voter registration lists or the lists of actual voters of the political subdivisions within the district or division. The plan shall prescribe some other source or sources of names in addition to voter lists where necessary to foster the policy and protect the rights secured by sections 1861 and 1862 of this title.

So yes, federal courts do in general primarily rely on state-supplied lists of registered voters. There are potential issues here:

What if you live in a state (i.e., North Dakota) that does not require voter registration? The first backup to that is a list of who voted.
What if the voter registration lists (or the actual voter lists in the case of North Dakota) are somehow deemed to not reflect a non-discriminatory, "fair cross section" of the residents of some district?

If there are possible "fair cross section" or discriminatory issues with those lists provided by the state/county, the federal courts may use sources in addition to those voter lists (with those other sources also mostly supplied by the state/county).
With regard to "why", The US does not have a national ID card. Except for North Dakota, those voter registration lists are the most comprehensive lists of who is qualified to serve on a US federal court jury. Not everyone drives a car. Some states have ID cards, others don't.
Every state (except North Dakota) has voter registration lists, and most states make those lists very inclusive, in part thanks to the National Voter Registration Act Of 1993. When you get a driver's license, simply check a box and you are registered to vote.

Isn't this just a definition of "prioritize"? The question was "why?"

@Barmar I updated my answer, but in reply to you, what else (excluding North Dakota)? As I noted, not everyone qualified to serve as a district court juror has a driver license. Not every state has a state ID card. Those voter lists are quite comprehensive, and automatically show that the person is at least 18 years of age, is a US citizen, and resides in the district (excluding moving, of course).

I think the question is "Why not just combine all these lists all the time?" rather than only adding the driver lists when the voter list seems to be incomplete.

@Barmar Merging has the potential to bring all sorts of problems. The same person might have slightly different names or different addresses on multiple lists. Noncitizens can get a drivers license in many states. People under 18 can get driver licenses in almost all states. Merging might well create more problems than it solves, and should only be done where failure to doing so appears to be necessary due to 8 U.S.C. sections 1861 to 1863.

"People under 18" -- licenses have the date of birth, it's easy to filter out under 18. And some states now allow people to vote at age 16 in local elections.

"Noncitizens can get a drivers license in many states ": Noncitizens can get a driver's license in every state.  "When you get a driver's license, simply check a box and you are registered to vote": this provision has also made it more likely for noncitizens to be registered to vote, typically unintentionally.
